# Html.DropDownList inside Editor Template generates wrong name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik-mvc

I have following drop down declaration in my EditorTemplate in file named `Category.cshtml`

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", categoryList, new { style = "width: 100%;" })
```

And it appears that it generates `Category.CategoryId` instead of expected `CategoryId` which I specified as a **name** attribute value.

What I am doing wrong? Is it possible get the name exactly that what I specified using Html.DropDownList?

**Update 1.**

I am using that editor template in a Telerik grid context:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<PriceCategoriesModel.PriceRuleModel>()
    .Name("pricecategories-grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(x => x.Id))
    .DataBinding(...)            
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.Vendor)
                    .Width(50);
            columns.Bound(x => x.Manufacturer)
                    .Width(100);
            columns.Bound(x => x.Category);
            //...
        }) //...)
```

Actually before I used Telerik's DropDown with the same name and name for select element was generated correctly.

Comment: Are you using your template for any table raw?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the view code where you use `@Html.EditorFor`

Comment: @PEO yes I used it in a table, please see updated question

Comment: Bingo.. give a unique ID for raw id and assigned it for drop down but it should have to match your model.

should have to remind you this I didn't use Telerik MVC frame work

@{
    string rowId = "lineItemRow" + @Model.Index;
    string lineItem = "YourModelListName[" + @Model.Index + "].";
    string idName = lineItem + "Id";

    string yourDropDownId = lineItem + "ApprovalStatusId";
    
}


 @Html.DropDownList( yourDropDownId , Model.YourDropDownList )

cheers

Comment: @PEO I cant put unique name there because this data submitted to the server and action expected CategoryId in request. Only "CategoryId"

Comment: Just add index property to your module and buy using that index you can create a unique ID. let me know if you need sample code. but correct me if I am going out of your scope.
cheers

Comment: @PEO it seems - yes, you are going in a wrong way as a real issue was that no matter what your yourDropDownId the result will be = "Category." + yourDropDownId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After decompiling `Html.DropDownList` I found that final field name calculated by prepending `this.HtmlFieldPrefix + "."` to specified name and trims "." after.

Then found how to set this prefix through `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`.

Then I put things together I got this terrible solution.

```
@{
    var oldHtmlFieldPrefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = String.Empty;
}

@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", categoryList, new { style = "width: 100%;" })

@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = oldHtmlFieldPrefix;
}
```

Don't want to use that - please tell me that there is another fancy build-in way to handle that.

Comment: The source code for MVC is freely available; no need for decompilation.  Anyway, the answer is just to write the HTML right into your view (you can wrap this in an HtmlHelper extension returning an MvcHtmlString if you want).

Comment: @emodendroket seems there is no fancy solution for that, I just looked for built-in solution as I didn't wanted to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose, but it ends up being a small level of effort anyway.  If you want to pursue it as an extension method I'd check out the TagBuilder class (you can equally well use Linq to XML but TagBuilder is probably simpler for what you want to do).